# Forking a child in another thread: parent doesn't receive SIGCHLD on termination

Tags: python, multiprocessing, posix

Normally, when a process *fork* a child process, it will receive a `SIGCHLD` signal if that child terminates. But, if this *fork* happens in a thread other than the *main thread* of the application, parent won't receive anything.

I test it in Python, on different GNU/Linux machines. All was `x86_64`.

My **question** is: Is it a Python behaviour, or is it a defined behaviour of POSIX Standard? And in both cases, why it is so?

---

Here is a sample code to re-produce this behaviour.

```
import signal
import multiprocessing
import threading
import time


def signal_handler(*args):
    print "Signal received"

def child_process():
    time.sleep(100000)

def child_thread():
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=child_process)
    p.start()
    time.sleep(100000)


signal.signal(signal.SIGCHLD, signal_handler)

p = multiprocessing.Process(target=child_process)
p.start()

t = threading.Thread(target=child_thread)
t.start()

time.sleep(100000)
print "Waked"
time.sleep(100000)
```

Then, send a `SIGKILL` to each child. When first child (the one forked in main thread) terminates, `signal_handler` will be called. But when second child terminates, nothing will happen.

I also test the same scenario with `os.fork` instead of `multiprocessing.Process`. Same result.

Comment: This is a known Python [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue21895). POSIX does not mandate such behaviour.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis It worths to be an answer. It's exactly the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is [documented python behavior](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html):

> only the main thread can set a new signal handler, and **the main
>   thread will be the only one to receive signals** (this is enforced by
>   the Python signal module, even if the underlying thread implementation
>   supports sending signals to individual threads). This means that
>   signals can’t be used as a means of inter-thread communication. Use
>   locks instead.

Comment: Right, but why this happens in my sample code? I don't want to communicate between threads, but I'm communicating between processes. The bug that `Michael Foukarakis' mentioned explains the problem more accurately.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.5 introduced a fix, of sorts. While posix doesn't guarantee which thread will receive the SIGCHLD (and as you can see Linux tends to deliver it to the thread which spawned the subprocess), it *does* guarantee that it will not deliver it to any thread which has blocked the signal. Python 3.5 exposes the pthread_sigmask function as `signal.pthread_sigmask`, so if you can make sure that all threads except for the main thread run

```py
signal.pthread_sigmask(signal.SIG_BLOCK, {signal.SIGCHLD})
```

then the signal is guaranteed to be sent to the main thread and python will call your signal handler.